# Использование слов г-н, г-жа

Tags: стилистика

У меня была задача проверить текст, переведённый с китайского на русский, на соответствие нормам русского языка. В тексте присутствовали обороты "г-н. Чжао", "г-жа Чен" и т.п. Насколько мне известно, в современном русском языке эти слова не употребляются. Но текст носит дипломатический характер. Может быть это стилистическая особенность дипломатических текстов? Стоит ли убрать слова "г-н", "г-жа"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы эти слова уберёте, получится обращение по фамилии, что в русском варианте в некоторых контекстах (официальное лицо или малознакомый человек) звучит невежливо. Поэтому для оценки чужого перевода нужно знать контекст (обращения меняются со временем - "господинов" /фамилия + xian sheng/ не было в эпоху культурной революции, но от другой дипломатической стороны его ожидать можно было) или иметь оригинал, чтобы отличить добавления "г-н/г-жа" или "товарищ" от непереводимых добавлений (сяо, лао - младший/старший друг или коллега и др.) перед односложными фамилиями при обращениях между знакомыми или коллегами. Если же "г-н" употребляется в 3-м лице, то необходимость сохранения этого слова в переводе зависит от степени официальности текста (напр. вряд ли оно нужно при ссылке на человека в новостях, но в этом случае обычно требуется полное имя).

**P.S.** Вместо Чен правильнее Ч**э**н (если с основного диалекта - по транскрипции Палладия). Возможно, такая статья пригодится:

http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/obraschenie-v-sovremennom-kitayskom-yazyke

Answer (score 3):

В современном русском языке эти слова употребляются, тем более в деловом стиле.
Вот выдержка из словаря.

В современной России форма вежливого обращения при фамилии или звании любого гражданина, независимо от его социальной или национальной принадлежности.
Слово  [господин](http://lingvostranovedcheskiy.academic.ru/119/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD) никогда не употребляется при ***имени человека***.

> В сочетании с указательным местоимением этот приобретает иронический или пренебрежительный оттенок. Такое сочетание относится к человеку (мужчине), который не пользуется уважением в обществе. Если за словом господин следует **не конкретная фамилия или звание определенного лица**, а что-либо другое, **это указывает на неизвестность человека (господин в черном)** или на обобщенность образа, как, например, в заглавии известного рассказа И.А. Бунина **«Господин из Сан-Франциско».**

**ГОСПОЖА**

> Форма женского рода от слова *господин*, а также — вежливое обращение при фамилии или звании женщины, независимо от ее социальной или национальной принадлежности. Форма множественного числа — *дамы*. Однако при обращении к группе лиц обоего пола употребляется только слово *господа*, а обращение *дамы и господа*, которое довольно часто звучит в публичной речи, является неправильным.

Слово  [**госпожа**](http://lingvostranovedcheskiy.academic.ru/#) никогда не употребляется при имени. В сочетании с указательным местоимением эта приобретает иронический или пренебрежительный оттенок. Если за словом госпожа следует не конкретная фамилия или звание определенного лица, а что-либо другое, это указывает на неизвестность человека (госпожа в автомобиле).

Подробнее здесь: [Россия. Большой лингвострановедческий словарь. — М.: Государственный институт русского языка им. А.С. Пушкина. АСТ-Пресс. Т.Н. Чернявская, К.С. Милославская, Е.Г. Ростова, О.Е. Фролова, В.И. Борисенко, Ю.А. Вьюнов, В.П. Чуднов. 2007.](http://lingvostranovedcheskiy.academic.ru/)

Comment: *Слово госпожа никогда не употребляется при имени* - это кто ж такое придумал-то? А как тогда обратиться к женщине? "Дама", что ли?))))  Масса примеров обратного. http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E3%EE%F1%EF%EE%E6%E0

Comment: В Нац.корпусе при слове "госпожа" - фамилии .

Comment: Ээээ.... А что  Вы в таком случае называете "именем"? *Слово госпожа никогда не употребляется при имени*. Если вы думаете, что трехчленное китайское имя состоит из имени и фамилии, вы глубоко ошибаетесь. В наших примерах Чжао - это не имя при рождении (given name). Это как раз некий аналог фамилии - родовое имя (family name). А имя в вашем понимании - то, что идет после. Разберитесь уж. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F

Comment: Я говорю не про Китайские имена, а про примеры в Нац.Корпусе. А про пример в вопросе я ничего не говорил.

Comment: *А про пример в вопросе я ничего не говорил*  - зачем тогда вы дважды написали *Слово господин никогда не употребляется при имени человека* и *Слово госпожа никогда не употребляется при имени*?

Comment: Писал не я, а автор словаря. Действительно, не употребляется! В словаре речь идет о русских именах собственных, а не о китайских. В китайских текстах, когда имя при рождении - это неких аналог фамилии, употребление слова "госпожа" представляется возможным.

Comment: Вы процитировали. И получается, что совершенно не к месту.

Comment: Автора интересовало, употребляются ли в современном русском языке слова "господин", "госпожа". Я ответил.  А чем в данном случае являются ***Чжао*** и ***Чен***  мне неизвестно. Поэтому,исходя из ответа, пусть автор сам решает, употреблять ли г-н,г-ж при ***Чжао*** и ***Чен*** .

Answer (score 3):

У вас не совсем точная информация. 
Слова эти (как часть именования при обращении только!) не употреблялись при общении между гражданами СССР, "братских" республик и членами коммунистических и рабочих партий. Во всех этих случаях "классово чуждое" обращение заменялось на "товарищ".

Во всех иных случаях "господин", "госпожа" а также "дамы и господа" было вполне возможным и даже предпочтительным. Вне всякого сомнения подлежало использованию в дипломатическом этикете - при должных обстоятельствах, разумеется.

С распадом СССР - а вместе с с ним и классовой идеологии, ограничений на употребление господин, госпожа не осталось.

Но тут, коли текст дипломатический, надо еще посмотреть, как в китайском принято обращаться официально. Допустимо ли вообще что-то типа "господин Чжен" - без второй части имени. Если да, то проблем нет. Но в известных мне переводных текстах имя пишется полностью. "Господин Чжао Вэньбин".

Вот примерный образец http://ru.minghui.org/html/articles/2006/3/10/38796p.html

"Господин" сокращается как "г-н", без точки. Но это только при обращении. Если в третьем лице, то лучше написать полностью.

Добавлю, хотя я думаю вы-то знаете, но больше для Сержа.

> Именование человека в китайской, а также связанных с ней культурах
>   отличается от системы имён, принятой на Западе. Наиболее заметным
>   признаком этого различия является то, что в китайском полном имени
>   сначала пишется фамилия, и только после неё — личное имя.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F

Здесь использованы термины "имя" и "фамилия" - это не совсем точные названия для китайской системы имен, но для первого приближения сойдет. Именно так - и только так воспринимают это китайцы. Первая часть - сокращение официального имени. **Господин Чжэн Динхэ** - сокращенно будет **господин Чжэн**, никак не "господин Динхэ" - это невозможно в принципе.

Answer (score 3):

**Употребление слов  "г-н", "г-жа" в деловых письмах**

http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2015/06/steuktura.pdf

1) Обращение "господин - господа", имевшее до 1917 года статус 
официального, в настоящее время **широко используется в различных сферах 
жизни нашего общества.**  Так обращаются в письмах к деловым партнерам, предпринимателям, банкирам, должностным лицам, деятелям искусства, политикам. При этом совершенно невозможно представить себе ситуацию использования этого 
обращения по отношению к социально незащищенным группам населения: 
"господа инвалиды", "господа беженцы", "господа безработные".

2) При обращении к конкретному физическому лицу используют **различные формы:** с индексом и без индекса, пофамильное и по имени-отчеству. В зависимости от степени близости с вашим корреспондентом, обращение может начинаться словами "Дорогой + имя" или "Уважаемый + фамилия", например: Уважаемый господин Васильев! Уважаемый г-н Иванов! Уважаемый Алексей Степанович, Дорогая Ирина Петровна!

3) **Отсутствие пофамильного и поименного обращения** допустимо только при 
наличии коллективного адресата и в трафаретных письмах, а также при 
адресовании письма юридическому лицу. В последнем случае в формуле обращения можно использовать наименование должности, например: **"Уважаемый господин директор!", "Уважаемый господин посол!".**

Если у адресата есть звание или титул, можно вместо обращения "господин" 
указать его. Во всех западноевропейских странах и США опускать титулы как в 
устной, так и в письменной речи считается невежливым. Однако писать и 
говорить "Господин + титул + фамилия" принято только в Германии.

4) **Слова "Господин" и "Госпожа" не принято употреблять без фамилии,** кроме 
того, их часто сокращают до "Г-н" или "Г-жа", тогда как звания и титулы 
предпочтительно писать полностью.